# Query to get the accounts shows no movement in February 2016 and the balance is less than $ 2,000.00

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to make a script to get the query that I need in the SQL, just what I try is to get the accounts showed no movement in the specified month and your balance is less than $ 2000 but though I try to make it in GROUP BY, but not given me an idea of how to divide customers who made movements among those who did not move their accounts, because my script is this:

```
DECLARE @FechaMovimiento VARCHAR(10)
SET @FechaMovimiento = '0000-00-00'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] a
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Depositos] b
                ON a.CuentaId = b.CuentaId
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Retiros] c
                ON a.CuentaId = c.CuentaId
                WHERE b.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento and b.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento 
                AND c.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento and c.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento
                )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('No existen clientes sin movimientos en el mes')
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] a
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Depositos] b
                ON a.CuentaId = b.CuentaId
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Retiros] c
                ON a.CuentaId = c.CuentaId
                WHERE b.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento and b.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento 
                AND c.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento and c.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaMovimiento
                --AND a.Saldo < 2000
                )
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] WHERE Saldo <= 2000
END
```

And it is not correct, although the data show, but if a customer made no move presents the results, but if a single client made some movement shows nothing ... and I'm super-confused about it ... I admit that I do not have many SQL knowledge

and i tried with this query too:

```
SELECT cb.*
FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] cb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM [dbo].[Retiros] r
              WHERE cb.CuentaId = r.CuentaId AND
                    r.FechaMovimiento >= '2016-02-01' AND
                    r.FechaMovimiento < '2016-03-01' 
             ) AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM [dbo].[Depositos] d
          WHERE cb.CuentaId = d.CuentaId AND
                d.FechaMovimiento >= '2016-02-01' AND
                d.FechaMovimiento < '2016-03-01' 
         )
         AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] WHERE Saldo < 2000)
```

The tables in order:

**AccountBank**

**Retiro/Withdrawal**

**Deposits**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cb.*
FROM   [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] cb
WHERE  cb.Saldo < 2000
AND   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM [dbo].[Retiros] r
              WHERE cb.CuentaId = r.CuentaId AND
                    r.FechaMovimiento >= '2016-02-01' AND
                    r.FechaMovimiento < '2016-03-01' 
             ) AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM [dbo].[Depositos] d
          WHERE cb.CuentaId = d.CuentaId AND
                d.FechaMovimiento >= '2016-02-01' AND
                d.FechaMovimiento < '2016-03-01' 
         )
```